# SharePoint Groups Magically Adding Themselves to Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, administration, groups

Please can anyone help?

We have a single SharePoint Site Collection in a massive tenant.

Under **People and Groups**, we keep seeing the following groups being added: **All Users (Windows), Everyone, Everyone Except External Users.**

We have specific permissions on all Lists and the addition of the above doesn't seem to affect it - but my question is, when I delete the above groups from people and groups the site collection, they magically come back under People and Groups?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Those are SharePoint default groups which does not have permissions on site/lists automatically. So, you can ignore those groups. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to stop them populating into people in groups?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any way to permanently remove those. But showing those under "People and Groups" does not mean they have permissions on the site. You can check the actual granted permissions on the site from "Site Permissions" page (generally, with URL like: `https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-name>/_layouts/15/user.aspx`).

Comment: So people in groups is just there to manage the actual structures of groups and people you could possibly use in your site but it doesn't mean they have any access until you use site permissions is that correct? So everyone except external users appearing under people in groups does not mean everyone in the world can access your site. It just means the group is there if you need to use it. If I did want to give everyone in my company access, I would have to add everyone except external users into the members group is this correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. They cannot access the site unless you add them under permissions/members group.

Comment: just to be clear do you mean 'they cannot access the site, unless you add them under the ***Site Permissions*** section

Comment: yes, that is correct. Let me know if it helps & answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

All Users (Windows), Everyone and Everyone Except External Users are the SharePoint out of the box groups which does not have permissions on SharePoint site/lists automatically.

I am not sure if there is any way to permanently remove those from People and Groups. However, showing those groups/users under "People and Groups" section does not mean that they have permissions on the SharePoint site.

You can check the actual granted permissions on the SharePoint site from "Site Permissions" page (generally, with URL like: `https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-name>/_layouts/15/user.aspx`)

The groups shown under "People and Groups" are there just as normal groups and admins could possibly use those in their site but it doesn't mean that they have any access until you add these groups under "Site Permissions" or "List Permissions" section explicitly. So everyone except external users appearing under people in groups does not mean everyone in the world can access your site. It just means that the group is there if you need to use it. If you want to give everyone in your company access to your site, you have to add everyone except external users into the "Site Permissions" section.

**Microsoft Documentations**:

1. [Share a SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-a-site-958771a8-d041-4eb8-b51c-afea2eae3658)
2. [Understand groups and permissions on a SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/understand-groups-and-permissions-on-a-sharepoint-site-258e5f33-1b5a-4766-a503-d86655cf950d)